# How to get First 100 characters from wikipedia api

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to retrieve the first 100 text characters from a Wikipedia API query.

I searched a lot on Google and Stack Overflow but have landed with no answer.
By searching I got all the text content but I just need first 100 characters.

Here is a working snippet of my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="article"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    
    $(document).ready(function(){

 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=Jimi_Hendrix&callback=?",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     async: false,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     
  var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
  var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
  
  // remove links as they will not work
  i.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
  
  // remove any references
  i.find('sup').remove();
  
  // remove cite error
  i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
  
  $('#article').html($(i).find('p'));
   
  
     },
     error: function (errorMessage) {
     }
 });    
    
    });
    
 
    
</script>
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use the [`action=query&prop=extracts`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts#API), not `action=parse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using substring/slice?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="article"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    
    $(document).ready(function(){

 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=Jimi_Hendrix&callback=?",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     async: false,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     
  var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
  var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
  
  // remove links as they will not work
  i.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
  
  // remove any references
  i.find('sup').remove();
  
  // remove cite error
  i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
  
  $('#article').html($(i).find('p').text().slice(0, 100));
   
  
     },
     error: function (errorMessage) {
     }
 });    
    
    });
    
 
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question has nothing to do with Wikipedia, but you can just use `substring()` to get the first `n` characters, i.e.,

```
"one two three four".substring(0, 8)
-> "one two "
```

Which in your case would be something like:

```
i.substring(0, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, we require only 100 characters from text contents in wiki page , we may iterate over paragraphs until we get at least 100 characters and then retrieve first 100 characters using method `slice`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="article"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   
    
  $(document).ready(function(){
  // extracting 100 length text content from stackoverflow page
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=Stack_Overflow&callback=?", 
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     async: false,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     
  var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
  var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
  
  // remove links as they will not work
  i.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
  
  // remove any references
  i.find('sup').remove();
  
  // remove cite error
  i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
    
         // whole paragraphs
   var paragraphs = $(i).find('p');
    
         // convert whole paragraphs to string
         var str = "";
         for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; ++i) {
            str += paragraphs[i].textContent;
            // break as soon as we get required length
            if (str.length >= 100 ) break; 
         }
   $('#article').html(str.slice(0,100));
   
    },
     error: function (errorMessage) {
   }
 });    
    
    });
    
</script>
```